# Hadoop Stream Job Error (Type mismatch in key from map)

Tags: r, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I know that there are few identical issues reported. 
In my case my case I wrote Mr. jobs on R in regular way. I know there is a way to use RHadoop to access hadoop directly from R though.

I execute my hadoop job as:

```
$hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.1.jar
-input test/test_r_mr -output RMR7 -file ~/mapper.R -file ~/reducer.R
```

The error looks like following:

> ERROR="java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Does anybody have any clue how to fix this using mapper/reducer written on R?

Thank you.